# Solving Dependency Resolution of source files in karma

Tags: javascript, jasmine, sapui5, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

We have built our application using UI5 library and written jasmine tests for these. We have difficulty in gettting the coverage for these javascript files.

- **Project Structure:**
  Currently, our project structure consists of the typical model, view, controller structure. We have around 1000 files kept in different hierarchies.
- **Problem at hand:**
  I am trying to get coverage for this project and trying out Karma for this. 
  With the default karma configuration, I ran the tests. The tests failed and  based on the logs I could see that karma expects all the files in the project to be listed in the order of their dependencies. This would be extremely difficult for me as the number of files is huge.
- **Questions:**

  1. Is my understanding of Karma right? Is providing all the files in the order of their dependency the only way?
  2. Does anyone know any alternate solution or alternate library where I can get coverage for my javascript files?

The complete karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'openui5'],
        openui5: {
            path: "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js",
            useMockServer: false
        },

        client: {
            openui5: {
                config: {
                    theme: 'sap_bluecrystal',
                    libs: 'sap.m,sap.bpm',

                    resourceRoots: {
                        "sap.bpm": "base/target/appresources/com/sap/bpm",
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        files: [
            'src/**/*.js' , 'test/**/*.js'

        ],

        preprocessors: {
            'test/**/*.js': ['coverage']
        },

        captureTimeout: 210000,
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 210000,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 210000,

        plugins: [
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-openui5',
            'karma-requirejs'

        ],
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
        port: 9878,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
        autowatch: false,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: true,
        concurrency: Infinity,
        coverageReporter: {
            includeAllSources: true,
            dir: 'coverage/',
            reporters: [
                { type: "html", subdir: "html" },
                { type: 'text-summary' }
            ]
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: can u share your whole karma.conf.js ?

Comment: @AshKander: I have shared my configuration

Answer (score 0):

Ok so : in the preprocessor entry, you have to specify which files you want to instrument for coverage.

In your conf file you set the test files for instrumentation, which is very unlikely to be what you want to achieve

switching to

```
preprocessors: {
  'src/**/*.js': ['coverage']
},
```

is likely to give you better results :)